# Displaying raw shortcodes in a Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress theme Flatsome which uses brackets [] in visual editor to output content. I would like to insert a function to theme functions.php which would disable content output and only **display the shortcodes as raw text + wrap it in pre tags**, just like this:

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE3rC.png)

Currently I am using this function to achieve the result, but it messes up the flow of other content:

```
function fv_render_raw_content($atts, $content = null)
{
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($content) . '</pre>';
}
add_shortcode('render_raw_content', 'fv_render_raw_content');
```

It causes headings inside the page (not wrapped by the function) to change order for no reason:

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SctD7.png)

I would really appreciate any ideas on what to change so other content flows according to the Wordpress visual editor and is not affected by the function. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try and see what happens if you use `<code>` instead of `<pre>`?

Comment: Tried using `<code>`, didn't work. The heading is still underneath :(

Comment: It is hard to guess the solution without seeing your css and html but you can try to this to your css `pre {display: inline}`

Comment: Sure, no problem. Here is the link to the page: [link](https://flatresources.com/elements/cta-split-horizontal/)

Comment: I checked your page and h2 heading is actually below the pre tag which is wrapped inside a span tag. So, this is the expected outcome of the html generated.

Comment: It is just outputted below :) this is how it looks like in wordpress visual editor : `<h2 class="heading-2">Shortcode</h2>

[render_raw_content]
[section label="*CTA: Horizontal with Pattern" padding="70px" class="cta-horizontal-pattern"]

[/section]`

Comment: I know how html works, basic display:block elements should flow one after another but in this case the h2 heading is moved underneath for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your shortcode, the content being outputted is being done so via echoing out which although is fine, however in order to maintain call stack priority from the theme, I'd recommend returning content inside your shortcode rather than echoing it out onto your page.

You also might want to look into wrapping your **$content** variable around some sort of a content sanitization method like **sanitize_text_field** to ensure that no additional markup is being added to the page from the where the shortcode is being used, and that whitespaces are also removed.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/

Another thing you can do is re-work your shortcode such that you have an attribute which is the heading text of the shortcode. This can then be sent in as a parameter to your shortcode function, and if you're echoing content into the page you would first do so by outputting the header, followed by the content which wraps those `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for your tip! However, I don't know a single thing about php, the function was created by someone else. Could you please show me how the adjusted function would look like with return instead of echo + sanitize? I don't know what to replace. Thank you very much